# unable to save image using selenium crop on Mac (python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, selenium, crop

I ran the script, it ended no wrong, but the cropped image was blank. The same script performed perfectly and saved the cropped image successfully on my friend's computer (Linux). I am new to selenium and don't know much about the computer system, any help is appreciated.

Here is the script:

```
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
# Time: 2018/7/16 19:38

from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
import time
from PIL import Image


def time_format():
    current_time = time.strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S',time.localtime(time.time()))
    return current_time

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('http://www.baidu.com/')

driver.save_screenshot("full.png")

element = driver.find_element_by_id("su")
print(element.location)
print(element.size)

xPiont = element.location['x']
yPiont = element.location['y']

element_width = xPiont + element.size['width']
element_height = yPiont + element.size['height']

picture = Image.open('full.png')

picture = picture.crop((xPiont, yPiont, element_width,element_height))
print(picture.size)
picture.save(time_format() + ".png")

sleep(2)
driver.quit()
```

the cropped image:
[the cropped image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/klFXp.png)

but it's supposed to be like this:
[the expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XnfbB.png)

some other info:
macOS High Sierra 10.13.3
python 3.5.2
selenium==3.13.0
Pillow==5.2.0

Comment: Perhaps this is just a simple cut-n-paste mistake, but your script has syntax errors.  `from PIL import Imageenter code here` is obviously wrong, and the first line of `time_format()` is not indented.  Please edit your question to contain the actual code you're running.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It's my first time to ask question on stackoverflow, made some stupid mistakes.  But the real problem is the resolution of the photo(full.png) which is too large. I reduced the resolution by half and it worked.